# Converting a date to a number for a Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

Hi i have a procedure that has in it

```sql
Select
(ROUND(A.START - A.END, 0) AS DAYS_WORKED
FROM WORKINGTABLE A
```

THIS RETURNS
5

super
when i put it in a procedure and update another table with the DATATYPE as NUMBER the info it says this it cant do it becasue the data type is not a number it is a date. fair enough. so I changed the column to a DATETYPE but it didnt like it and gave an error saying invalid month (as the date and time is 5 im not suppriesed it didnt like it)

so I set the column back to NUMBER
and tried this

```sql
TO_NUMBER(ROUND(A.START - A.END, 0))) AS DAYS_WORKED
```

and this

```sql
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ROUND(A.START - A.END, 0))) AS DAYS_WORKED
```

but it still thinks it is a date and gives this messag

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE.

shows fine in a query output/report it is just the procedure being fussy

any ideas how i can get this to line up?

Comment: Hi Oliver  I cannot use DATEDIFF on Oracle SQL

Comment: Please update your question with the full code for the procedure you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was me not realising how `insert` into works.

I thought it was inserting on the name of the `select`, but it wasn't. It was inserting in order of the column (something I can't change in oracle), so when it was saying it was the wrong format, it was because the column it was supposed to be going into wasn't the right one. It ignores the names and does it in order.

Thanks to Lightfoot for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You did something wrong (can't tell what exactly). Have a look at the following test case.

Sample table; `days_worked` is - as you said - a number:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, days_worked number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);

1 row created.
```

Procedure accepts `date` datatype parameters. Difference of two dates is number of days between.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_id in number,
  2    par_date_start in date, par_date_end in date) is
  3  begin
  4    update test set
  5      days_worked = round(par_date_end - par_date_start, 0)
  6      where id = par_id;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> begin
  2   p_test(1, to_date('05.12.2022 13:43:22', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  3             to_date('28.12.2022 08:23:32', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID DAYS_WORKED
---------- -----------
         1          23

SQL>
```

---

So, yes - it works when properly used.

Comment: Yes it seems to be the precedure that doesnt like that it is comming from DATE.                    the error says        **********Connecting to the database WORKINGTABLE.
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
ORA-06512: at "WORK.WORKINGTABLE", line 55
ORA-06512: at line 2
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database WORK

Comment: As you probably know, we can't debug code we don't see. We don't have your procedure, don't know which parameters it expects nor what you provided when calling it. Make sure that **everything matches** because - as demonstrated - it *works* OK if everything is done right.